# Cross Tab Query Detail Data

Tags: mysql, pivot, crosstab

I have a following table in mysql

```
  id int(11) 
 time_table_id int(11) ,
  week_day int(11) ,
  time_from datetime ,
  time_to datetime ,
  syllabus_detail_id int(11) ,
  room_id int(11) ,
  faculty_id int(11) ,
  is_recess bit(1) ,
 can_log bit(1)
```

**[i have written cross tab or pivot query as follows](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2b789/2)**

The problem i am facing is in this image

> [image]

The first two rows are been seperated but should be shown as merged row.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help. Well i have found the solution but i don't know whether is a legitimate way to produce the output or not. If anybody interested in the answer let me know. I will paste the SQL query for the problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `faculty_id` has a different value on those first two rows, `Nimit` and `Nimit1`. The GROUP BY is seeing those two rows as distinct.

Comment: Yes the faculty_id in both the cases should be shown in single row and same column . I am nowise to such kind of queries. I think i need to run sub query but it gives error saying that sub query returns more than one row.